# private module function in pybind

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a simple C++ function e.g

```
std::string debug_print(const Expression& exp)
{
    Graph g = compile(exp);
    return g.to_string();
}
```

That I'm trying to expose in the python module e.g

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m)
{
    m.def("_debug_print", &debug_print);
}
```

So that this function is not imported when using

```
from my_module import *
```

But I can still access it for debug purposes when importing it directly.
The code compiles and the module is constructed, but when I try to import the private function directly like this:

```
from my_module import _debug_print
from my_module import *
```

I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_debug_print'
```

How can I expose a function as private with pybind?

Comment: The exposed function is called `_debug_print`, not `_print_flow_dot`.

Comment: oops, forgot to change the name for the question, thanks!

Comment: could you add the import statement you are using for your test?

Comment: @StefanoBuora added, thanks.

Comment: as a hint, not knowing the answer: are you importing another function from the same module? (it would guarantee that python can reach your library). Again, when you change the code to solve that issue, only as a check, change the name of another function in order to be sure that your very last build is in use. (seeing the "other function" import error would tell you if the last build is in use)